# Disable template processing in Tornadoweb

Tags: angularjs, tornado

I have to use Tornadoweb as RESTfull backend for our existing AngularJs application.

The {{}} are heavily used in the angular app. I would like to serve angular files from tornado as static files

**Is there a way to disable processing templates by tornado to avoid conflicts with {{}} used by tornado?**

I know how to change the  {{}} in the angular app with $interpolateProvider but it will involve a lot of changes in the angular app.

As a temporary solution, I put the angular app in the static folder of tornado and used a redirect:

```
class IndexHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect(self.static_url('ng-app/index.html'),True)
```

It is working but it is not a nice solution because The url displayed is some thing like :

```
http://localhost:8080/static/ng-app/index.html?v=efb937e6a0cb0739eb0edfd88cfb4844
```

Any better idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use {{!tag}} to disable the translation of tornado.

Comment: Finally it is what I did, but I had to change all the {{tag}} to {{!tag}} in my existing code. Which is not The good choice of course.

Comment: This is not a solution of a sufficiently large project.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Tornado's built in StaticFileHandler. This passes everything as static files to Angular:

```
from tornado import options, ioloop, web

options.define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

SETTINGS = {
    "debug" : True
}

application = web.Application([
    (r'/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "angular_app"})
],**SETTINGS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options.parse_command_line()
    application.listen(options.options.port)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: For those who need more clarification. This works for me without using '!' sign everywhere. Take note in this sentence   (r'/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "angular_app"}). 'angular_app' is the folder where your webpage file can be located. And you need to type in the browser like this 'http://localhost:8888/index.html' if 'index.html' is located in 'angular_app' folder.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky and quite ugly solution: you can just use `self.write()` instead of `self.render()` to print  contents of file. If it's a HTML page, then there will be more GET requests for .css, .js files and images so you have to have second handler to return them all. Example for AngularJS application from: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-get-first-impression

Project tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── angular_app
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   └── bootstrap.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── ajax-loader.gif
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── contollers
│       │   └── CurrencyConvertCtrl.js
│       ├── db.js
│       ├── models
│       │   └── Currency.js
│       ├── _references.js
│       └── vendor
│           ├── angular.js
│           ├── bootstrap.js
│           ├── highcharts.js
│           └── jquery-1.9.1.js
├── test.py
└── test.py~
```

Tornado code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

import logging

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

import os 
angular_app_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "angular_app")

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        with open(angular_app_path + "/index.html", 'r') as file:
            self.write(file.read())     

class StaticHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): 
        self.set_header('Content-Type', '') # I have to set this header
        with open(angular_app_path + self.request.uri, 'r') as file:
            self.write(file.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[(r'/', IndexHandler), (r'/js.*', StaticHandler), (r'/cs.*', StaticHandler), (r'/img.*', StaticHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: nice hack Nykakin, is this the standard way AngularJS should be used with tornado to get around the template notation. Q (I ask myself) Is there a way to turn templating off in tornado?

Comment: Isn't using `self.write()` instead of `self.render()` same as turning rendering off? You don't have to render anything if you don't want to.

Answer (score -1):

dumb way:

just use:

```
self.render('some-template.html', var1='{{var1}}')
```

since `{{var1}}` the template removes first the `{{ }}` and then replaces the `var1` so the result will be `{{var1}}` in the rendered html file ;)

Comment: What if you have `username`, `avatar` and many other variables. I give a minus 1 because this approach is not scalable.

Comment: @KhanhHua This answer has same scalability problem as the accepted answer has