# Skip serverside rendering in tornado

Tags: templates, tornado

The syntax of tornado template engine is `{{varName}}` which incidentally matched with the Angular's data binding syntax.

Is there any decent way to skip server-side rendering of tornado template engine? Changing in HTML file with a new syntax will mess the project a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable template processing in Tornadoweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284286/disable-template-processing-in-tornadoweb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest possible way would be to not use `self.render`. Instead, `open` the file and use `self.write` to serve it:

```python
class MyRequestHandler(...):
    def get(self):
        with open('path/to/template.html') as f:
            self.write(f.read())
```